# Add a TCombobox Column to a Firemonkey TGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

This question *appears* to have been answered already, possibly by MonkeyStyler/Mike Sutton, however, as I am using Delphi 10 Seattle, provided code and guides don't work anymore. Specifically

[firemonkey grid basics](http://monkeystyler.com/blog/entry/firemonkey-grid-basics-custom-cells-and-columns)

doesn't work because the ApplyStyling event handler is only called once now (at column create)

I want to add a TCombobox or TComboboxEdit column to aTGrid.

```
type
  TComboColumn = Class(TColumn)
  protected
    function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl; override; // works!
  End;
```

...

```
Grid1.AddObject(TComboColumn.Create(Grid1));
```

...

```
    function TComboColumn.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
    begin
      Result := TComboBox.Create(Self);
      TComboBox(Result).Items.Add('A');
      TComboBox(Result).Items.Add('B');
      TComboBox(Result).Items.Add('C');
      TComboBox(Result).OnChange := DoTextChanged; // strange hooks
    end;
```

This creates the combobox column in the grid, but it's the *same* combobox in every row, and I have no idea how to add the GetValue and SetValue methods applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do quite much. Let's start.
At first you need declare some data type that will store the values for your `ComboBox` column.

```
  TComboRecord = record
    FieldValues: array of string;
    ItemSelected: integer;
    function Selected: string;
  end;


...
{ TComboRecord }

function TComboRecord.Selected: string;
begin
  Result := FieldValues[ItemSelected];
end;
```

and populate a `TList<TComboRecord>` with some data.

```
var
  ComboData: TList<TComboRecord>;
procedure PopulateComboData(Rows: cardinal);

implementation

procedure PopulateComboData(Rows: cardinal);
var
  RowI: cardinal;
  i: cardinal;
  ComR: TComboRecord;
begin
  for RowI := 1 to Rows do
  begin
    Setlength(ComR.FieldValues, random(5) + 1);
    for i := 0 to length(ComR.FieldValues) - 1 do
      ComR.FieldValues[i] := inttostr(random(64000));
    ComR.ItemSelected := 0;
    ComboData.Add(ComR);
  end;
end;

initialization

ComboData := TList<TComboRecord>.Create;

finalization

ComboData.Free;
```

Than you need create a `TComboBox` ascendant so that it could store and manipulate the `TComboRecord` type data.

```
  TComboBoxCell = class(TComboBox)
  private
    FComboData: TComboRecord;
    procedure SetComboData(const Value: TComboRecord);
    function GetComboData: TComboRecord;
  protected
    procedure SetData(const Value: TValue); override;
  public
    property ComboData: TComboRecord read GetComboData write SetComboData;
  end;
...

{ TComboBoxCell }


function TComboBoxCell.GetComboData: TComboRecord;
begin
  FComboData.ItemSelected:=ItemIndex;
  result:=FComboData;
end;

procedure TComboBoxCell.SetComboData(const Value: TComboRecord);
var
  s: string;
begin
  FComboData := Value;
  Items.Clear;
  for s in Value.FieldValues do
    Items.Add(s);
  ItemIndex := Value.ItemSelected;
end;

procedure TComboBoxCell.SetData(const Value: TValue);
begin
  inherited;
  ComboData := Value.AsType<TComboRecord>
end;
```

Than you need to inherit a new class form `TColumn`:

```
  TComboColumn = class(TColumn)
  protected
    procedure DoComboChanged(Sender: TObject);
    function Grid: TComboExtendedGrid; overload;
    function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl; override; 
  end;
...

{ TComboColumn }

function TComboColumn.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
begin
  Result := TComboBoxCell.Create(Self);
  TComboBoxCell(Result).OnChange := DoComboChanged;
end;

procedure TComboColumn.DoComboChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: TPointF;
  LGrid: TComboExtendedGrid;
begin
  LGrid := Grid;
  if not Assigned(LGrid) then
    Exit;
  if FUpdateColumn then
    Exit;
  if FDisableChange then
    Exit;
  P := StringToPoint(TFmxObject(Sender).TagString);
  LGrid.SetValue(Trunc(P.X), Trunc(P.Y),
    TValue.From<TComboRecord>(TComboBoxCell(Sender).ComboData));
  if Assigned(LGrid.FOnEditingDone) then
    LGrid.FOnEditingDone(Grid, Trunc(P.X), Trunc(P.Y));
end;

function TComboColumn.Grid: TComboExtendedGrid;
var
  P: TFmxObject;
begin
  Result := nil;
  P := Parent;
  while Assigned(P) do
  begin
    if P is TCustomGrid then
    begin
      Result := TComboExtendedGrid(P);
      Exit;
    end;
    P := P.Parent;
  end;
end;
```

You see that now we have to subtype `TGrid` class as well as we have to get its handler by `Grid` function and need access to `protected` `FOnEditingDone` variable

```
  TComboExtendedGrid = class(TGrid)
  private
    FOnEditingDone: TOnEditingDone;
  protected
    procedure SetValue(Col, Row: integer; const Value: TValue); override;
  end;
{ TComboExtendedGrid }

procedure TComboExtendedGrid.SetValue(Col, Row: integer; const Value: TValue);
begin
  inherited;

end;
```

Finally we need set the necessary creation and event handliing mechanism in our form unit. Add a column variable to the from declaration.

```
  protected
    CCColumn:TComboColumn;
```

populate the ComboData and create the column:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PopulateComboData(Grid2.RowCount);
  CCColumn:=TComboColumn.Create(Grid2);
  CCColumn.Parent := Grid2;
  CCColumn.Header := 'CB';
end;
```

and handle the events:

```
procedure TForm1.Grid2GetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer;
  var Value: TValue);
begin
  case Col of
     6{Combo Column Number}: Value:=TValue.From<TComboRecord>(ComboData[Row])
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Grid2SetValue(Sender: TObject; const Col, Row: Integer;
  const Value: TValue);
begin
  case Col of
      6{Combo Column Number}: ShowMessage(Value.AsType<TComboRecord>.Selected);
  end;
end;
```

Do not forget to pass changes (if you need) to `ComboData` list. The current handlers will not do this for you. I prefer making this in `Grid2SetValue` event handler.

Comment: This looks very promising and comprehensive (way above my ability to write, but readable to me). Will accept as answer when I've had a chance to test it thoroughly. Thanks!

Comment: Let's get this straight. I got it all sorted now. There are 2 things I changed for D10. 1. `StringToPoint` is now in `FMX.Utils` 2.   `s := Value.AsType<TComboRecord>.Selected;` in `Grid1.SetValue` causes an AV in D10. I have replaced that with `ComR := Value.AsType<TComboRecord>;
      if ComR.ItemSelected > -1 then
        s := ComR.FieldValues[ComR.ItemSelected];` for D10. Then it works just fine.

Comment: I also added 3. `type
  TComboColumn = class(TColumn)
  private
    FUpdateColumn: Boolean;
    FDisableChange: Boolean;` as compared to the XE7 version that I got working first.

Comment: @nolaspeaker You can try to write `ApplyStyle` and `ApplyStyling` procedures for setting the presentation (font color, font size etc.) of the cell controls as well. It is very comfortable to pass necessary flags using `TComboRecord` as a container.

Comment: I have no experience with `ApplyStyle` and `Applystyling`, but more importantly, my next question is about the grid display. The currently selected value of the combobox is only shown when the cell is actually selected, otherwise the cell just shows (record). Is that a long answer?

Comment: @nolaspeaker Actually I don't understand you. You've written '_currently selected value of the combobox is only shown_ _otherwise the cell just shows (record)_'. Can you receive the necessary functionality in a simple `TComboBox` instance placed on your form? Anyway. You need to start a new question for this.

Comment: Read my question again. Anyway, thanks for all your help on this.

Comment: @nolaspeaker have you ever gotten this to work? I am getting the (record) in the combo box all the time.. :\

Comment: I am using Delphi 10.1 now, and I simply added a TPopupColumn to the TGrid. Much easier.

Comment: @nolaspeaker You excavated a really old question that is almost 1.5 years old. Time flies like an arrow... The way I showed you than has been perfectly working for me all this time.

Comment: For some reason I got a recent notification of that comment and I responded to it the same hour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy way to add a Combobox to a FMX TGrid. Granted, this solution has the same items in every combo, but that's all I can achieve right now.

```
type
  TComboColumn = class(TPopupColumn)
    function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl; override;
  end;
```

...

```
function TComboColumn.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
var
  ComR: TComboRecord;
  i: Integer;
begin
   Result := TComboBoxCell.Create(self);
   // now they all have the same drop-down values
   ComR := frmMain.ComboData[0];
   for i := 0 to Length(ComR.FieldValues) do
     TComboBoxCell(Result).Items.Add(ComR.FieldValues[i]);
end
```

... And just for continuity

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   AGrid := TComboExtendedGrid.Create(Self);
   AGrid.Parent := Self;
   AGrid.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
   AGrid.Options := AGrid.Options + [TGridOption.AlwaysShowEditor];
   AGrid.OnGetValue := AGridGetValue;
   AGrid.OnSetValue := AGridSetValue;
   AGrid.RowCount := 5;

   ComboData := TList<TComboRecord>.Create;
   PopulateComboData(AGrid.RowCount);

   CCColumn := TComboColumn.Create(AGrid);
   CCColumn.Parent := AGrid;
   CCColumn.Header := 'Combohere';   
end;
```