# Extending class from another unit

Tags: delphi, helper, class-helpers

We can extend any class so:

```
TColumn = class(FMX.Grid.TColumn)
private
  FId: Integer;
public 
  property Id: Integer read FId write FId;
end;
```

And this is works fine in our own unit, but if we try this (`Grid: TGrid` on the form):

```
procedure ChangeId;
var
  Col: TColumn;
begin
  Col := Grid.Columns[0];
  Col.Id := 0;
end;
```

We got error:

> [dcc32 Error] uHelpers.pas(136): E2010 Incompatible types:
>   'uHelpers.TColumn' and 'FMX.Grid.TColumn'

Any way to extend `FMX.Grid.TColumn` class to make procedure `ChangeId` correct?

Comment: Your issue is one of scoping. Why call your class TColumn, when there's already a FMX.Grid.TColumn? You expect the compiler can tell the difference? Call you class TMyColumn. Now at what point did the Grid get a collection of TMyColumns? It never did. That's an entirely different problem!

Comment: I'm understand this problem and my question about this problem. This is completely impossible?

Comment: It's possible. Just do it in a different way. [Add a TCombobox Column to a Firemonkey TGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920219)

Comment: No, your issue is not one of scoping. Your issue is that the grid won't create instances of your column class.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is right. the column objects are `FMX.Grid.TColumn` instance in the grid. you can't assign them into your TColumn type and use its id property because it does not exist there.

Comment: Thanks to @nolaspeaker idea and some additional sources this problem solved. Possible question sounds incorrect, I don't need to extend any class, this question is for Grid Columns only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is possible, but we should to add columns manually at runtime:

```
TIdColumn = class(FMX.Grid.TColumn)
private
  FId: Integer;
public 
  property Id: Integer read FId write FId;
end;

Grid.AddObject(TIdColumn.Create(Grid));

procedure ChangeId;
var
  Col: TIdColumn;
begin
  Col := Grid.Columns[0] as TIdColumn;
  Col.Id := 0;
end;
```