# How to add a component to a TGrid column?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to add an EditBox and button (just as an example) to a Grid's Column as a child in Delphi 10.2/10.3. It looks fine during design-time, but completely disappears at runtime. As I assumed, those components are redrawn by the cells.

I've tried different simple steps, like reducing cell opacity, forcing them to be visible, bringing them to front, etc, but it nothing works.

In addition, the cells behind the components are not editable, so the components are blocking these cells but sort of invisible.

Is it possible to make them visible during runtime? I'd appreciate any ideas.

To clarify, I am not trying to fill rows and cells with these components. All that I need is to see and use them where I place them.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32920219/62576 shows you how to do this with a combobox. The steps should be the same for a TEdit, so it should give you a starting place. It's not simply a matter of creating the controls and putting them in the grid.

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for the link. I've already seen it but it was about adding a component in cells. I only need to see the previously added component. Do you know why these components disappear during the run-time? Does that have something to do with drawing cells?

Comment: What is the purpose of these button or other controls. What should happen when you scroll the grid, should the button stay foot (and visible) or scroll with the grid? Why can you not place them above the grid? What other components did you plan to use similarily? For what platforms? Are you using styles?

Comment: My point was that it's not as simple as dropping a control on the grid. That will never work, and you're wasting time trying. See the points @TomBrunberg raises, for instance. The proper  way to do it is shown in the post I linked. If that doesn't work for you, then I suspect you're out of luck.

Comment: Hi @Tom, I've already added the necessary components above the grid but I was looking for a more robust solution without creating a new component. I think it will require much more efforts simply because I haven't done it for a long time. Answering all other your questions, this is Windows platform, I actually intended using only editboxes as a filtering mechanism (the same way as old Access solutions, not sure about current ones) and yes they ideally they should move together with the grid.

Comment: Thank you, Ken, I've got your point. I am just trying to understand the logic behind. I will have a closer look at the provided solution. Maybe I'll find the answers there.

Comment: It might be better (and maybe even cheaper) to get a 3th party grid for this. Not only will you get your controls on your grid easier but also gain other features it supplies out of the box. The price for such a 3th party often is less then the price for all your hours. An example can be devexpress